# _formatPrice in Magento is returning ""

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, format

I have my own custom block which extends "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select" core block.

With in one of its function I'm using the following code to get priceStr with currency symbol.

```
$priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                'is_percent'    => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'))
            );
```

Every thing is working perfect except **when the price is 0.0000** it returns "" (empty)

I would like it to return **$0.00** when the price is **0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to extend the abstract class of **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract**

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php#L114

Highlighted is the issue, as if price formatting value is 0, a return of "" condition is met.

If you are already extending **getValuesHtml** in Type/Select you should be able to simply redefine your own method in your same class, since it is extending the Abstract class needed.

```
/**
 * Return formated price
 *
 * @param array $value
 * @return string
 */
protected function _formatPrice($value, $flag=true)
{
    //if ($value['pricing_value'] == 0) {
    //    return '';
    //}

    $taxHelper = Mage::helper('tax');
    $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

    $sign = '+';
    if ($value['pricing_value'] < 0) {
        $sign = '-';
        $value['pricing_value'] = 0 - $value['pricing_value'];
    }

    $priceStr = $sign;
    $_priceInclTax = $this->getPrice($value['pricing_value'], true);
    $_priceExclTax = $this->getPrice($value['pricing_value']);
    if ($taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {
        $priceStr .= $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_priceInclTax, $store, true, $flag);
    } elseif ($taxHelper->displayPriceExcludingTax()) {
        $priceStr .= $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_priceExclTax, $store, true, $flag);
    } elseif ($taxHelper->displayBothPrices()) {
        $priceStr .= $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_priceExclTax, $store, true, $flag);
        if ($_priceInclTax != $_priceExclTax) {
            $priceStr .= ' ('.$sign.$this->helper('core')
                ->currencyByStore($_priceInclTax, $store, true, $flag).' '.$this->__('Incl. Tax').')';
        }
    }

    if ($flag) {
        $priceStr = '<span class="price-notice">'.$priceStr.'</span>';
    }

    return $priceStr;
}
```

Be sure and use the codebase version you are using, as the above is CE 1.9 and may differ, also there is most likely a reason why a check of a 0 value occurs as other methods below the line may fail. Code above is untested.

A Stackoverflow question that may help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705577/how-to-override-magento-formatprice-function-to-only-show-prices-including-tax

Comment: I have noticed the same and thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Magento helper function to format price and when the field is empty it appears like €0,00.

Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFullPrice(), true, false);